# firebase auth/admin-restricted-operation

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, ejs

i am trying to use firebase authentication with node.

this is my index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signOut } = require('firebase/auth');

const authRouter = express.Router();
const auth = getAuth();

authRouter.get('/', (req, res) => {
//   open auth/views/main.html
  res.render('main.ejs', { root: './views' });
});

authRouter.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;

  try {
    const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    const user = userCredential.user;

    res.status(200).json({ message: '회원가입 성공', user });
  } catch (error) {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;

    res.status(400).json({ message: '회원가입 실패', errorCode, errorMessage });
  }
});

authRouter.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;

  try {
    const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    const user = userCredential.user;

    res.status(200).json({ message: '로그인 성공', user });
  } catch (error) {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;

    res.status(400).json({ message: '로그인 실패', errorCode, errorMessage });
  }
});

authRouter.post('/logout', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await signOut(auth);

    res.status(200).json({ message: '로그아웃 성공' });
  } catch (error) {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;

    res.status(400).json({ message: '로그아웃 실패', errorCode, errorMessage });
  }
});

module.exports = authRouter;
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { getAuth } = require('firebase/auth');
const { initializeApp } = require('firebase/app');
require('dotenv').config({ path: '.env' });
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

const app = express(); // create an instance of express
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // use the body-parser middleware

const authRoutes = require('./auth/index');
app.use('/auth', authRoutes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

main.ejs

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/auth/signup" method="POST">
    <h1>회원가입</h1>
    <div> email : <input type="email" name="email" id="signUpEmail" /> </div>
    <div> password : <input type="password" name="password" id="signUpPassword" /> </div>
    <button type="submit" id="signUpButton" >회원가입 하기</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

i tried to signup but it showed me the admin-restricted-operation error.

when i used postman it worked well. but if i tried in the web, it gives me error.

plz help me,,

i tried to signup but it showed me the admin-restricted-operation error.

when i used postman it worked well. but if i tried in the web, it gives me error.